# GCM Invalid JSON Missing Payload

Tags: python, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send messages through Google Cloud Messaging, using Python sleekXMPP. I tried to follow the sample in the [GCM docs](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#implement). However, I am getting an "InvalidJson : MissingPayload" error response (400) when I call `send_command`. What am I missing here? The following is the code that I use.

```
def random_id():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(8))

class GcmNotifier(sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP):

    def __init__(self, jid, password):
        super(GcmNotifier, self).__init__(jid, password)
        self.add_event_handler('message', self.on_message_received)

    def send_gcm_message(self, message):
        body = '<gcm xmlns:"google:mobile:data">%s</gcm>' % json.dumps(message)
        print(body)
        self.send_message(mto='', mbody=body)

    def on_message_received(self, message):
        print(message)

    def send_command(self, recipient):
        self.send_gcm_message({ 
            'to': recipient,
            'message_id': random_id(),
            'data':
            {
                'hello': 'world'
            }
        })

xmpp = GcmNotifier(GCM_SENDER_ID + '@gcm.googleapis.com', GCM_API_KEY)
if xmpp.connect((GCM_SERVER, GCM_PORT), use_ssl=True):
    xmpp.process(block=False)
```

This is the error that I receive:

`<message to="REDACTED@gcm.googleapis.com/475DBA7C" type="error" xml:lang="en"><body>&lt;gcm xmlns:&quot;google:mobile:data&quot;&gt;{&quot;to&quot;: &quot;REDACTED&quot;, &quot;data&quot;: {&quot;hello&quot;: &quot;world&quot;}, &quot;message_id&quot;: &quot;ZGDZ9QTD&quot;}&lt;/gcm&gt;</body><error code="400" type="modify"><bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" /><text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">InvalidJson : MissingPayload</text></error></message>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out SleekXMPP was automatically enclosing my message in `<body />` tags, which is not the expected message format by the GCM server. I ended up solving the problem by defining my own stanzas, like this:

```
 class Gcm(ElementBase):
    namespace = 'google:mobile:data'
    name = 'gcm'
    plugin_attrib = 'gcm'
    interfaces = set('gcm')
    sub_interfaces = interfaces

class GcmMessage(ElementBase):
    namespace = ''
    name = 'message'
    interfaces = set('gcm')
    sub_interfaces = interfaces
    subitem = (Gcm,)

register_stanza_plugin(GcmMessage, Gcm)
```

and then by sending the message like this:

```
def send_gcm_message(self, message):
    msg = GcmMessage()
    msg['gcm'].xml.text = xml.sax.saxutils.escape(json.dumps(message, ensure_ascii=False))
    self.send(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving for `Missing Payload` is because you are not passing any parameter as Key and value format to be recognized as payload.

First you have to define a function where you are going to pass the payload and then covert it back to the plain text after the GCm server responds back.

Here is an example:

```
def plaintext_request(self, registration_id, data=None, collapse_key=None,
                          delay_while_idle=False, time_to_live=None, retries=5, dry_run=False):
if not registration_id:
        raise GCMMissingRegistrationException("Missing registration_id")

    payload = self.construct_payload(
        registration_id, data, collapse_key,
        delay_while_idle, time_to_live, False, dry_run
    )
```

You can have the exponential Back-Off mechanism if you need to have in your code that would ping the server after some duration.

For the detail code implementation, please read the following [document](https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm/blob/master/gcm/gcm.py).

Comment: Doesn't this count as the payload: `{ 
            'to': recipient,
            'message_id': random_id(),
            'data':
            {
                'hello': 'world'
            }
        }`
Or is there something wrong with my format?