# java - send message error using smack4.2 firebase xmpp

Tags: java, spring-mvc, firebase, xmpp, smack

I am trying to send a message. Connection with firebase xmpp server is done. I am using latest smack 4.2.

```
  public myClient(String senderId, String serverKey) throws IOException, NotConnectedException, InterruptedException {
        Roster.setRosterLoadedAtLoginDefault(false);
        Jid jid ;
        jid = JidCreate.from(HOST);
        final XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration conf = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .setCompressionEnabled(false)
                .setSendPresence(false)
                .setConnectTimeout(10000)
                .setHost(HOST)
                .setDebuggerEnabled(false)
                .setPort(PORT)
                .setXmppDomain((DomainBareJid) jid)
                .setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault())
                .setUsernameAndPassword(senderId + "@gcm.googleapis.com", serverKey)
                .build();

        this.conn = new MyXMPPTCPConnection(conf);
        try {
               conn.connect();

            conn.login();

        } catch (XMPPException | InterruptedException | SmackException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }



        Roster roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(conn);
        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
        for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
            System.out.println(entry);
        }
            Entity jEntity  ;

            Jid jid1 = JidCreate.from("text");

            EntityBareJid jid21 = JidCreate.entityBareFrom("ak@gcm.googleapis.com");


            Chat chat = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(conn)
            .createChat(jid21);

             Message newMessage = new Message();
             String t = "hello this is a test message";
            newMessage.setBody(t.toString());
            /* ((Object) chat).send(newMessage);*/
            chat.sendMessage(newMessage);

        StanzaFilter filter = new AndFilter(new StanzaTypeFilter(Message.class));

        //PacketCollector myCollector = conn2.createPacketCollector(filter);
        // Normally, you'd do something with the collector, like wait for new packets.

        StanzaListener myListener = new StanzaListener() {
            @Override
            public void processPacket(Stanza packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException {
                System.out.println("packet = [" + packet + "]");
            }
        };
        conn.addAsyncStanzaListener(myListener, filter);

        while (true) {
        }
        //conn2.disconnect();
    }
```

When I am running this method got the following error

> packet = [hello
>   this is a test
>   message25667738-6dd1-4c74-a64b-2fdbac74339bInvalidJson :
>   MissingPayload]
>       Jul 26, 2017 12:52:46 PM
>
> org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader parsePackets
>   INFO: MyXMPPTCPConnection[438277974557@gcm.googleapis.com/41CA77F0]
>   (0) received closing  element. Server wants to terminate the
>   connection, calling disconnect()

Please review and suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCM Invalid JSON Missing Payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393534/gcm-invalid-json-missing-payload)

Answer (score 1):

The FCM XMPP Server uses JSON syntax. So you need to use the systax as described for FCM payload in [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref). Since XMPP uses XML, you need to embed the JSON payload in an xml node with the name gcm as follows:

```
<gcm xmlns:google:mobile:data>
  JSON payload
</gcm>
```

For e.g, your JSON payload may look like this:

```
{
  "to":"APA91bEXJvW4jUdxxxxx-xxxxxxxx",
  "data":{"message":"Hello"},
  "priority":"high"
}
```

For complete details on using the XMPP Connection Server using GCM/FCM, take a look at [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs).

Using Smack you can create a class with the **GcmPacketExtension** to create the gcm element with the json payload.